# iOS Only add unique object to NSMutableOrderedSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an NSMutableOrderedSet. I download an array of "Person" objects. Each Person object has a unique id.

What is the most efficient way to only add Person objects that are not already in the NSMutableOrderedSet?

I can obviously iterate through the entire set and if the id does not exist at the end then add it - but that seems like the slowest way to do it.

Ideas?

What I am doing:

```
for (int x = 0; x < existingSet.Count; x++)
{
  if ([personA isEqualto: personB])
      break;
  if (x == existingSet.Count - 1 && ![person isEqualto: personB])
      [existingSet addObject: personA];

}
```

Comment: I get it now. I knew that sets offered the unique ordering I wanted, but just couldn't figure out how to use it. I went through the class docs and looked at the available methods and saw nothing like addIfUnique - but I didn't know you used isEqual to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to teach your person class what equality means, as  a set will only add new object if they are found not to be equal to any other object. do so by overwriting `isEqual:` and `hash`

```
@interface Person : NSObject
@property (strong) NSNumber *identifier;
@end

@implementation Person
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
  return [self.identifier isEqualToNumber: object.identifier];
}

- (NSUInteger)hash {
  return [self.identifier hash]; // if the only field to determine uniqueness is `identifier`, this hashing method is enough
}
@end
```

than all you have to do is

```
[existingSet addObject: personA];
```

this will lead to the same set as

```
[existingSet addObject: personA];
[existingSet addObject: personA];
[existingSet addObject: personA];
[existingSet addObject: personA];
```

as only one equal objects can be added. the other `addObject:` calls will fail silently.

---

a good read: [NSHipster: Equality](http://nshipster.com/equality/)

Comment: Apple provides a good article for this.  Before your specialized test, you can do a faster test for deep equality as well as for inherited equality.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectComparison.html

Comment: hmm, the line `if (![super isEqual:other]) return NO;`is weird in apple's article, a for sure it will always return `NO` for different objects.

Comment: That's true for immediate subclasses of NSObject, but some intervening subclass might have implemented it's own equivalence check.  This says we'll AND the check with the super's implementation.

Comment: sure, but in that documentation it looks broken.

Comment: OP implies that the id defines uniqueness, evaluating other fields than that would be wast of time.

Comment: But my question is about iteration - using this method I would still have to hit the end of the existing list before I knew if the object exists in the set right?

Comment: no. not right. you just add it to an mutable set. if it is unique, it will be added. also sets do have ordering, they there for aren't list. you cannot add something to an end if it doesn't have an end.

Comment: Ok that is what i was trying to figure out. I read through the nsmutableorderedset docs but didn't see anything saying i need to use isEqual to make this work.  What data structure are they using behind the scenes to do this?

Comment: hmm, the easiest way to figure that out would be getting hired in the foundation department at apple.

Comment: no, seriously: parts of apples codes are open source, you can read that. but actually there are hints that apple must be using patched version or even independent code in their foundation classes.

Comment: this is an interesting article, though it is about arrays. http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/03/05/exposing-nsmutablearray/

Comment: @vikingosegundo what about getting the result of checking against the list. ie BOOL isInList = ??

Comment: @Spentak: why? if you do any comparison on your own, you loose every advantage of sets: fast adding and getting of objects via hashing. enforced uniqueness via isEqual and hashing. Stop treating sets like arrays!

Comment: So I have two tableviews where the datasources are these sets. I need to solve this problem if( person.hasCheckedIn && personIsInFirstTable) //then animate cell to the second table . We are continually refreshing data, but we can't just refresh the table, we have to show when someone has checked in via an animation (ie the changed cell moving into the other table)

Comment: this can be solved in many ways, but it has nothing to do with sets but the way how you implement the datasources. you should post a new question about that.

Comment: @Spentak, have a look at the docs for member: on NSSet.  This is the definitive idea for all the set subclasses.