# Objective-C: Selectively combine two arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I am aware of how normal `NSArray` concatenation works in Objective-C. This is not that question.

I have data that is being incrementally updated from a web service. My object has the following class definition (with a lot removed):

```
//  NoteTemplate.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface NoteTemplate 

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *objectId;
```

I am caching a list of these on-device and checking at launch to see if there are any new or updated `NoteTemplate` objects in my database to load. So, I end up with two arrays:

```
NSArray <NoteTemplate *> *oldArray
NSArray <NoteTemplate *> *newArray
```

If there are **no updates**, then all I need to do is simply concatenate the two arrays together and that's that.

If there **are updates**, however, I want to combine the two arrays, but whenever there is a common `objectId`, the item in `newArray` should take precedence over the item in `oldArray`.

Thus far, I am brute-forcing it like this:

```
- (void)updateNoteTemplatesWithArray:(NSArray *)newTemplates {
    NSArray *oldTemplates = [self getNoteTemplates];
    NSMutableArray *combined = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:newTemplates];
    for (NoteTemplate *noteTemplate in oldTemplates) {
        NSArray *matches = [combined filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id blockTemplate, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *bindings) {
            return [((NoteTemplate *)blockTemplate).objectId isEqualToString:noteTemplate.objectId];
        }]];
        if (matches.count == 0) {
            [combined addObject:noteTemplate];
        }
    }
    [self setNoteTemplates:[combined copy]];
}
```

Is there a more optimized way to do this? I can't see that this will affect performance at all, so perhaps an optimization is unnecessary. Still, this approach feels hacky and way over-engineered.

Comment: Do you really care about order rather than duplicity? What about using a Dictionary with key `objectId`, and sort them afterwards if needed? Maybe a `NSMutableOrderedSet` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587420/ios-only-add-unique-object-to-nsmutableorderedset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend @Larme's suggestion with Set usage you can try the following approach:

```
@interface NoteTemplate: NSObject

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *objectId;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *text;

- (instancetype)initWithObjectId:(NSString *)objectId text:(NSString *)text;

@end

@implementation NoteTemplate
- (instancetype)initWithObjectId:(NSString *)objectId text:(NSString *)text {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        _objectId = objectId;
        _text = text;
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
    return [self.objectId isEqualToString:[object objectId]];
}

@end
```

And the usage code:

```
NoteTemplate *nt1 = [[NoteTemplate alloc] initWithObjectId:@"1" text:@"old set"];
NoteTemplate *nt2 = [[NoteTemplate alloc] initWithObjectId:@"2" text:@"old set"];
NoteTemplate *nt3 = [[NoteTemplate alloc] initWithObjectId:@"1" text:@"new set"];
NoteTemplate *nt4 = [[NoteTemplate alloc] initWithObjectId:@"3" text:@"new set"];

NSSet <NoteTemplate *> *oldSet = [NSSet setWithObjects:nt1, nt2, nil];
NSSet <NoteTemplate *> *newSet = [NSSet setWithObjects:nt3, nt4, nil];

NSMutableSet <NoteTemplate *> *mergedSet = [newSet mutableCopy];
[mergedSet unionSet:oldSet];

for (NoteTemplate *note in mergedSet) {
    NSLog(@"Set item %@ %@", note.objectId, note.text);
}
```

After executing this code you'll see in the log:

```
Set item 3 new set
Set item 1 new set
Set item 2 old set
```

I assume that's what you were looking for.

Comment: That's a nice approach. I assumed that order was important in my answer, but maybe not.

Comment: @TomHarrington In case order is important `NSOrderSet` might be used as you recommended. Then `mergedSet` should be created from `oldSet` instead and `unionSet` function should be replaced with `[[mergedSet minus:newSet] union:newSet]`

Comment: Oh right. I've been doing Swift so much that I forgot to look for `NSMutableOrderedSet`. Instead I looked at `NSOrderedSet` and didn't think to look for extra mutability methods.

Comment: I ended up using a modified version of this because order *does* become important for me, but not during the portion where I am combining the arrays. I also needed to be able to remove items, so I added the `hash` method in addition to the `isEqual:` method. Thanks for getting me most of the way there!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'd call this *elegant* but it's a less brutish approach. Instead of filtering `combined` at every pass through the loop, get all the new IDs in advance and check the ID list in the loop.

```
    NSMutableArray <NoteTemplate *> *combined = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:newTemplates];
    NSArray <NSString *> *newTemplateIds = [newTemplates valueForKey:@"objectId"];

    for (NoteTemplate *oldTemplate in oldTemplates) {
        if (![newTemplateIds containsObject:oldTemplate.objectId]) {
            [combined addObject:oldTemplate];
        }
    }
```